# Из ассоциативного массива в многомерный php

Tags: php, json

Есть ассоциативный массив, в значениях которого находятся строки. Мне нужно сделать части ассоциативного массива многомерными если там находится больше 1 строки разделенной запятой. Если обычным explode он создает массивы для всего что видит, пример

```
(
    [Brand] => Array
        (
            [0] => iphone
        )

    [Model] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [Width] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.38 in (inches)
            [1] => 60.54 mm (millimeters)
            [2] => 6.05 cm (centimeters)
        )
)
```

А мне получается нужно: где строка не разделена запятой оставлять ее в прежнем состоянии

```
Array
(
    [Brand] => iphone

    [Model] => 12
        
    [Width] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.38 in (inches)
            [1] => 60.54 mm (millimeters)
            [2] => 6.05 cm (centimeters)
        )
)
```

код

```
//получение массива значений
$valSpaces = array_map('trim', $valius);
// созданием многомерного 
$finvals =  array_map(fn($el)=>explode(',', $el), $valSpaces);
//объединение с ключами 
$specifications = array_combine($keySpace,$finvals);
```

Comment: ну пропиши if для explode. если частей больше чем 1 - массив, иначе вернуть ту строку

Comment: В этом и заключается трудность, ибо я не понимаю как составить условие

Comment: покажи весь свой код (добавь в вопрос) куда ты пытался что-то сделать через explode

Comment: ну теперь стреложной функции не получится, придется писать через function с телом....в переменную вначале делаешь explode....а потом return с тернарником, который я описал выше

Comment: Я переписал стрелочную функцию на обычную, теперь выглядит просто так `$finvals = array_map('cube', $valSpaces);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = ['Brand' => ['iphone'],'Model' => [12],'Width' => [2.38,60.54,6.05]];
$second_arr = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(count($value) == 1) $second_arr[$key] = $value[0];
    else $second_arr[$key] = $value;
}
```