# Как записать условие для проверки ассоциативного массива и перехода в многомерный php

Tags: php, php7

Есть ассоциативный массив, в значениях которого находятся строки. Мне нужно сделать части ассоциативного массива многомерными если там находится больше 1 строки разделенной запятой. Если обычным explode он создает массивы для всего что видит, пример

```
(
    [Brand] => Array
        (
            [0] => iphone
        )

    [Model] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [Width] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.38 in (inches)
            [1] => 60.54 mm (millimeters)
            [2] => 6.05 cm (centimeters)
        )
)
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать условие чтобы оно создавало массив только там, где находится больше чем одно слово и получалась вот такая запись

```
Array
(
    [Brand] => iphone

    [Model] => 12
        
    [Width] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.38 in (inches)
            [1] => 60.54 mm (millimeters)
            [2] => 6.05 cm (centimeters)
        )
)
```

вот часть когда отвечающая за это

```
function cube($n)
{
    return explode('`',$n);
}

//получение массива значений
$valSpaces = array_map('trim', $valius);
// создание многомерного массива
$finvals =  array_map('cube', $valSpaces);
//объединение с ключами 
$specifications = array_combine($keySpace,$finvals);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Из ассоциативного массива в многомерный php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1396572/%d0%98%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-php)

Comment: Я вам в прошлом вопросе написал как. explode выделить в отдельную переменную а в return прописать тернарник, если количество элементов больше 1 - вернуть массив, иначе $n

Answer (score 1):

```
function cube($n)
{
   if(strpos($n,',')!==false)
      return explode(',',$n);
   else 
     return $n;
}
```